# Questions on Uniswap Fees keep Changing

Tags: blockchain, swap, uniswap

I am doing a research on Uniswap, but I can't find explanations regarding its Swap UI.

[image: Uniswap Swap]

What I want to know is what the 0.275% in the second row means.

I am well aware that Uniswap collects transaction fees for the liquidity pools, but the number I keep mentioning keeps changing and even seem to be positive at times.

Is the 0.275% a liquidity pool fee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hover over the number it says `The estimated difference between the USD values of input and output amounts.` as you can see in the screenshot below:

[image]

You can read more about pricing in the uniswap [docs](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/concepts/advanced-topics/pricing).